# New to latex, don't know why this \maketitle command is showing error?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am new to latex and trying to use a conference template. This error is popping up for the \maketitle command and I have tried many things which did no help:

```
                         
l.72 \maketitle
               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Here is what I have in .tex file:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

%===============================================================================

\begin{abstract}
```

And here is where the .sty file has defined the \maketitle command:

```
% create title
\providecommand{\maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    % for perfect author name centering
    \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox to \z@{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
    % The footnote-mark was overlapping the footnote-text,
    % added the following to fix this problem               (MK)
   \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \parindent 1em\noindent
      \hbox to 1.8em{\hss $\m@th ^{\@thefnmark}$}##1
    }
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \@maketitle
    \@thanks
    \@notice
  \endgroup
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\relax
}
```

The generated Pdf looks just fine, but the error prevails. Please enlighten me, if you understand what is going on.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. Without knowing your documentclass and packages this will be impossible to answer.